# Connect to a server using share name not IP not working

Tags: networking, server, mount, windows, samba

To connect to my server, I go either to "Connect to Server" or hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to browse location, then I type `smb://myserver.mywork.es//mysharedfolder` and enter my login credentials but then I get the below error message saying

> Unhandled error message: Failed to mount Windows share: Name not
>   unique on Network

But if I tried connecting using IP instead `smb://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx//mysharedfolder` and enter my login credentials it works well.

The server I’m trying to connect to has multiple IPs. But I want to call it with the share name instead of IP as my server assigns the IP with the least load soI want to connect using the sharedname not IP, any help?

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue in the past, in my case, it was due to the window server having multiple IPs addresses, and the SMB stack not being able to handle that well. You could overwrite the name with just one IP in `/etc/hosts` and retry.

Failing that, take a look in `/var/log/syslog` and see if there is any more details associated with the error, we'd need more details to help.

Comment: Yes, the server I’m trying to connect to has multiple IPs. But I want to call it with the share name instead of IP as my server assigns the IP with the least load.

Comment: Makes sense for load balancing -- but I've always had to assign a single IP to get SMB to work properly. Perhaps others will have a method that helps. I've always just pinned the hostname to one of the IPs via `/etc/hosts` on the client, which will let you reference it by hostname, but you do lose the load balancing.